# Best resource for integrating Skype API into ASP.Net website?

Tags: asp.net, api, skype

What's the best resource for integrating Skype API into ASP.Net website? I can't seem to find much on Skype.com's developer section.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by best resource? Just put the dll to Bin folder and start using the api..? I'm also new to api ant I think Skype client must be installed to the server.